# npm install http-server -g is not working

Tags: node.js

I am running npm install http-server -g and getting below error

silly fetchPackageMetaData error for http-server@latest 400 Bad Request: http-server@latest
9 verbose stack Error: 400 Bad Request: http-server@latest

can any one suggest what is going wrong in this command

Comment: Which npm version are you using ?

Comment: npm version is 5.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Try Below command

```
npm install http-server --save
```